# Indefinite Integral Using Substitution

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

can someone please help?

I need to evaluate this indefinite integral:

$$\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+2}}dx$$
I tried using substitution for letting *u = x*, but I can't get past finding the antiderivative after that.

Thank you!

Comment: This one $\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+2}}dx$?

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I couldn't format it the right way

Comment: try $u=\sqrt{x^2+2}$

Comment: $u=x$ is not very useful, try one that simplifies the argument of the square root, e.g., $u=x^2+2$.

Comment: I'd suggest writing the root as $\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{2}+1}$ then putting $\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}=\sinh t$.

Comment: But then again I didn't notice that, modulo constants, we have the derivative of the root's argument as a numerator :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you want to set $u = x^2+2$ which means $du=2x*dx$. We see an $x$ in the integrand which is good but we don't see a $2$. We can make up for this by saying.
$$\int{\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+2}}} = \frac{1}{2}\int{\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2+2}}}$$
And now we can use our $u$ substitution to get.
$$\int{\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+2}}}=\frac{1}{2}\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}du}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sqrt{u}}{\frac{1}{2}}+C=\sqrt{u}+C$$
Substituting $x^2+2$ back in for $u$ we find that.
$$\int{\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+2}}}=\sqrt{x^2+2}+C$$

Answer (score 1):

Letting $u=x$ doesn't accomplish anything.  Try letting $u=x^2+2$.

Answer (score 0):

write the integral inthe form
$$\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2+2}}dx$$ and set $$x^2+2=t$$